# How can i create JSF application with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsf

I'm trying to create a JSF Spring Boot application. This is what I coded:

My pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
    instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>tn.esprit.tp</groupId>
    <artifactId>tp.spring.mvc.rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>tp-spring-mvc-rest</name>
    <description>TP Spring</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
            <artifactId>rewrite-integration-faces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
     
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

faces-config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
              version="2.2">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

SpringBootApplication:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"tp.spring.mvc.rest"})
public class TpSpringMvcRestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  implements CommandLineRunner{
    
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TpSpringMvcRestApplication.class.getName());
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TpSpringMvcRestApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean rewriteFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean rwFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean(new RewriteFilter());
        rwFilter.setDispatcherTypes(
                EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR));
        rwFilter.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return rwFilter;
    }
```

The controller:

```java
@Scope(value = "session")
@Component(value = "userController") // Name of the bean in Spring IoC
@ELBeanName(value = "userController") // Name of the bean used by JSF
@Join(path = "/", to = "/login.jsf")
public class UserController {
        
    public void doLogin() { 
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }
}
```

XHTML login Page:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        template="/template/template.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="page_name" value="Connexion" />
        <ui:define name="menu">
            <h:form id="form">
                <b>Connexion</b>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Login (Email)" />
                    <h:commandButton id="btn" value="Connexion"
                        action="#{userController.doLogin()}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

The problem is that, when I click to connexion button, the method in controller is not called and I receive a Whitelabel Error Page.

How can I resolve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try change this :

```
return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml");
```